# C# While loop is infinite when using ||

Tags: c#, while-loop, logical-operators, logical-or

```
namespace GuestBook
{
    internal class GuestTracker
    {
        
        public static (string fullName, int guestCount) NameLog()
        {
            int guestCount;

            Console.Write("Welcome to the Cliffview Venue, " +
                "Hubbard's Wedding check in, what is your first and last name? ");
            string fullName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write($"\nHello {fullName} how many people will be joining you today? ");
            string guestCountText = Console.ReadLine();

            while (int.TryParse(guestCountText, out guestCount) == false)
            {
                Console.Write("\nSorry that wasn't a vaild number of guests, please entar a count using only the 0-9 characters: ");
                guestCountText = Console.ReadLine();

            }

            Console.Write($"So we have a total of {guestCount} guests, is this correct? ");
            string correctCount = Console.ReadLine();

           ** string no;
            while((no = correctCount.ToLower()) != "yes" || no != "no") 
            {
                Console.Write("\nI'm sorry, was that a yes or no? ");
                correctCount = Console.ReadLine();

            }
**
            if(correctCount.ToLower() == "no")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("\nOkay let's start over then.");
                NameLog();

            }


            return (fullName, guestCount);
        }



    }
}
```

I was attempting to run the second while loop so that it stops when yes or no are entered into the `correctCount` variable. When I take the `||` out and just have yes or no it works but as soon as I introduce the `||` it will loop infinitely.

I really only need the no response checked so I've modified my code, but the bug is bugging me. Why is it looping and not accepting "yes" or "no with the `||`?

Comment: A possibly clearer alternative is pattern matching: `while (correctCount.ToLower() is not "yes" and not "no")`.

Comment: I'd recommend using the `Console.WriteLine()` function.

Comment: You are saying _"if this string isn't 'no' or it isn't 'yes'  do something"_. No string is both "yes" and "no" at the same time so your OR condition is always _true_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every string is either not equal to "yes" or not equal to "no". I.e., "yes" is not equal to "no", "no" is not equal to "yes", and any other string is not equal to both of them. You should be using the logical and (`&&`) operator, not the logical or operation (`||`):

```
while((no = correctCount.ToLower()) != "yes" && no != "no")
    // Here ---------------------------------^
```

Comment: Can confirm this worked. Does that mean in general with != you don't use || ? You would use || with == instead?

Comment: No, it means that you should understand how logic works. Read it out loud in your native language and consider what it means. "I have a string, if it is not 'no' or it is not 'yes'". OK, I have a string "xyz", it's not "no", cool, true. What about "no". It is "no", so the first evaluation is false. It's not "yes", so the second evaluation is true. Now consider that `false` OR `true` resolves to true, si the statement is `true`. All possible strings are simultaneously either not "no" or not "yes".

Comment: Thank you both! Yes I'm here asking because I was unclear on the logic with !=. I was overthinking the logic or maybe underthinking. In a ( | | ) statement if one is true, the statement is true, loop will continue. In a ( && ) statement both must be true, if one is false the loop will stop. I've got it now.